# Java Collection that maps each element to a field of that element

Tags: java, list, collections

I have e.g a `List<Cat>` with class `Cat` containing a field of type `Tail`. I want a `List<Tail>` providing a live-view of the tails of the cats from the first list. Is there some known List implementation that accepts another List and a mapping Function like `cat -> cat.tail`?

Comment: No there is no such stuff available. All you can get is a _snapshot_ by extracting all tails from all cats, but that won't update itself if one cat "updates" his tail into another one (i.e. `cat.tail = new Tail();`).

Comment: What you need to do is extend `AbstractList<Tail>` and implement `get(int)` and `size()`.

Comment: @Tom It would naturally update itself, if the List implementation delegates all the methods to an underlying `List<Cat>` with the mapping function `cat -> cat.tail` I mentioned.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah, that would be a minimal implementation, but there's so much more to the List interface than just `get` and `size`.

Comment: But that's all you need to implement if you use `AbstractList`.  All the rest is done for you.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my "No", but that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

guava's `Lists.transform` does exactly that: [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#line.553)

in your example `tails = Lists.transform(cats, Cat::getTail)`